# Phpunit ignoring env settings for laravel configuration value

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Consider the following config file, `app\config\someFeature.php`

```
<?php

/* SomeFeature toggles */
return
    [
       'product_listing' =>
         [
           'full_listing_enabled' => env('FEATURE_PRODUCT_LISTING', false),
           'test_mode'            => env('FEATURE_PRODUCT_LISTING_TEST_MODE', false),
         ]
    ];
```

In the code, (a queued job), variable is called as follows:

```
if (config('features.product_listing.full_listing_enabled')) {
  // do something ..
}
```

For some reason values are not picked up when set in `phpunit.xml`

```
<server name="FEATURE_PRODUCT_LISTING_TEST_MODE" value="true"/>
```

I also tried with

```
<env name="FEATURE_PRODUCT_LISTING_TEST_MODE" value="true" force="true"/>
```

Dumping env('FEATURE_PRODUCT_LISTING_TEST_MODE') in code works when value is set in the .env, but is unset when I add the variable to `phpunit.xml`.

I would really like to avoid using a `.env.testing` file, and not have the tests depend on this configuration being set in the .env.

Is there a reason this variable is not set?

Comment: Are you using the `sync` queue driver?

Comment: @apokryfos - Yes, sync queue